# webpack devServer proxy doesn't catch my request

Tags: node.js, webpack-dev-server

I have a UI app on `http://localhost:8050/` and api server on `http://foo.local.bar.com`.
I logged in to the server directly, but I need the UI to send to cookie to the server too when I fetch GET method `http://foo.local.bar.com/myapi/api/goo/maa` .
In my config json I added `devServer` with proxy but it doesn't seem to work :

```
 devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api/*': {
        "target": "http://foo.local.bar.com",
        logLevel: 'debug',
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: true,
        withCredentials: true,
        cookieDomainRewrite: "localhost",
        onProxyReq: proxyReq => {
          console.log("onProxyReq 1 !!!!!!!!") // I don't see any console logs, so I also think the proxy doesn't "catch" my request...
          proxyReq.setHeader("Cookie", ".MYCOOKIE=123445"); 
          console.log("onProxyReq 2 !!!!!!!!", proxyReq)
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

But I still get "Authorization has been denied for this request." 401 error.

Any ideas? I tried, like, everything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what helped me eventually:

```
proxy: {
      '/myapi/api/*': { // changed the url
        target: 'http://foo.local.bar.com/', 
        headers: {
          Cookie: "MYCOOKIE=123445" // moved cookie to here
        },
        logLevel: 'debug',
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: true,
        withCredentials: true,
      }
    },
```